# .NET Framwork 3.5 Offline Unattended Install

Tags: windows-10, .net, unattended, dotnet-framework

I'm trying to install dotNet 3.5 on Windows 10 22H2. The target has no monitor and no access to the internet. When using the flags suggested by Microsoft `/q /norestart`, the package is not installed. Trying those flags on a similar machine with a monitor connected, the GUI "Download and install this feature" still shows up and needs a confirmation.

What I've done:

I've downloaded the offline installer from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net35-sp1. (dotnetfx35.exe)
I followed the deployment guide here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/guide-for-administrators.
I'm executing all commands from an elevated shell.

The guide suggests using `/q /norestart`. Other sources suggest `/quiet` and/or `/nopatch`. I've had no success with any combination of all the mentioned flags.

Using the DISM method is not an option since I don't have a way to mount an Windows installation image onto the target.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it with:

1. Extract or mount a Windows 10 ISO on your host
2. Copy the file `microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab` from `ISO\sources\sxs` onto the target
3. Install with `dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to install .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 10.

Open the Add/Remove Programs Control Panel (appwiz.cpl)

Click on Turn Windows features on or off

Click the box for .NET Framework 3.5

[image: .NET 3.5]

Comment: As mentioned, I do not have access to the Windows GUI since there is no monitor attached.

Comment: @sailektiv: No-one does. Use your Configuration Management solution to deploy it. The binary installer is for Windows XP. 99% of applications developed under .NET 3.5 run perfectly fine on .NET 4.0, which was released 15 years ago, so you may want to explore other options that are actually feasible.

Comment: The software which I need to install asks specificly for .NET Framework 3.5. The installer will not continue when 3.5 is not installed.

Comment: @sailektiv: This isn't specific to an ancient release of .NET Framework. Any organization that doesn't have the ability to perform this type of servicing remotely using their Configuration Management solution either needs to physically attend the system or send out a system that is already installed/configured.